# How to perform HTTP POST from within container running in Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, rest, flask, containers, azure-container-instances

I have a quick and dirty REST API that I have written in Python/Flask and deployed to an Azure Container Instance with a public IP address. As part of the functionality I call out to another resource in the usual way:

```
response = requests.post(api_url, json=query_body, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

The logs show a connection error saying that the name or service is not known:

> ERROR:app:Exception on / [GET]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn
> (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
> for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] **Name or service not known**

The service definitely exists. Do I need to configure the container in any way? Open ports for HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have NSG configured for these services?

Seems the service you are calling the api url, does not have access to connect to internet (I am assuming your other service is hosted on internet and you are calling it via public IP).

As the error says "gaierror", this occurs when the url cannot be resolved to an IP because there is no access to internet or DNS server is misconfigured.

You can either allow internet access to the calling service in NSG if that is the case or check why is the service unable to connect it internet (misconfigured DNS?).